# Controlling how, when, and if child controls are drawn (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, gdi+

I am writing an application in .NET that has a plugin interface.  That plugin interface provides several ways to draw information (controls) onto the surface of the application window.  While there are several reasons why I am doing this, the main reason is to provide custom colorization to text, either through the use of a graphic or directly manipulating the color of the text based on the background color.  I do this through the use of a "text mask" which is a black and white bitmap that works as an "alpha" map to let the Paint method know where to apply the texture/color changes.

The plugin developer has the option of using regular text (such as with a label), mask text (which is drawn to the mask rather than as a regular control), OR letting the user decide.  To go along with this, I have provided a modified label class that can either be drawn "normally' (when the text mask is not set for the control), or to the text mask when the User OR Developer decides (depending on what the plugin developer wishes to offer to the user).  Here is the class's code so that you understand how this is being done:

```
public class MaskingLabel : Label
{
    private static readonly SolidBrush maskBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    public Bitmap Mask { get; set; }
    public MaskingLabel() : base() { }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mask == null)   
            base.OnPaint(e);
        else
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Mask);
            g.DrawString(Text, Font, maskBrush, Location);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that this approach requires that I handle controls in a very specific order so that the form is drawn correctly.  I need to find the most efficient approach to get the tasks listed below done in the order given.  I have thought of three possibilities discussed further down.  For reference, this is the order in which tasks must be done:

1. All "MaskingLabel" controls that have the bitmap object set to the mask must be drawn first so that the mask is created before the next step.
2. The mask is applied to the background picture.
3. The resulting Bitmap is drawn in a way similar to the way a background would be drawn (except that it is modified first).
4. The rest of the controls are drawn as normal.

Is there a way for me to insure this happens without separating the controls manually?  My first guess is no.  As such, I have a few guesses below about how I should go about this. I was hoping someone with more in depth knowledge of GDI+ could offer some insight.

1. One idea that has occurred to me is to draw the masked controls during the OnPaintBackground method.  However, I don't want to waste time by painting the controls twice.  This means I would need to filter out which controls are drawn during the main Paint method which effectively leads us to option 2 (FAIK):
2. I can manually filter out the controls which draw to the mask so that they don't get added to the control.  My question here though is would they get drawn at all?  Can I manually force them to invoke the OnPaint method?
3. If doing that wouldn't work, then perhaps I can create a separate derived panel control to serve as a "backdrop" child control that acts as the background picture which can be forced to be drawn first?

**EDIT (With Part of the answer)**:
I realized after posting this that I already have part of the solution built into my project.  Still, I think it is a legitimate question to ask, so if anyone can add insight beyond what I have done in my description below, it is welcome.

Specifically, my project has only two controls that are added to the "root" form: a bar that goes to the top (docked at the top when it is shown), and a transparent panel that occupies the rest of the space (with a dock style set to fill).  So my solution would be to add the mask controls to the main form and add all the rest to the panel.  **This only leaves one remaining issue to be resolved:  How do I make sure that the panel and the bar are drawn last?** (As part of step 4 in the first list?)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I wasn't sure how to tag System.Windows.Forms.